# Android multiple gradient xml

Tags: android, gradient, drawable

is there a way to have 2 gradients in a drawable xml using either a `<layer-list>` or `<shape>` or some combination of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your clarification in Roman Nurik's response, I think what you're looking for is centerColor.

```
<gradient startColor="#00FF00" centerColor="#FFFF00" endColor="#FFFFFF"></gradient>
```

Comment: what if we want to have more than 3 colors?

Comment: No, you can't have more than 3 colors in a single gradient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not... a layer list drawable that references two shape drawables sounds like it would work. Have you tried that?

Comment: yeah i did, it works except for one thing: there's no way to make the gradients go from 0-50% and 50% - 100% of the drawable.  they only allow for absolute values.... which sucks.

Comment: Ah, I'd update the original question to be something like "how do I create gradients that have intermediate color steps." That sounds a little more clear than the original question :)